# Writing in a text File in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, file-io, io

I wrote a very simple piece of code, It was working perfectly since yesterday but now not working and even after lots of research/debugging i have not got the issue

```
 import java.net.InetAddress;
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;

  public class DetectLoggedInUser{

  public static void returnUserName()
  {
   String computerName;
   try {


     File file =new File("d:\\TestFolder\\UsersloggedIn.txt");

        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }


            FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
                BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
            String content= "\n UserName="+System.getProperty("user.name")+ " || Date and Time= "+new Date();
            bufferWritter.write(content);
            bufferWritter.close();

}

catch(Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
returnUserName();
}
}
```

Now file is created but nothing is being written in file

Is there anything wrong with this code(keeping in mind it was working since yesterday)?

Comment: Just pass `file` to the `FileWriter` constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Date;

public class DetectLoggedInUser {

    public static void returnUserName() {
        try {
            File file = new File("d:\\TestFolder\\UsersloggedIn.txt");

            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file, true);
            BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
            String content = "\n UserName=" + System.getProperty("user.name")
                    + " || Date and Time= " + new Date();
            bufferWritter.write(content);
            bufferWritter.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        returnUserName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion "Just pass file to the FileWriter constructor. " .... It works. But I am failed to understand why is it so, why "file.getName()" suddenly stopped working? if you could please enlighten me.

Comment: I don't believe that it has ever worked. `file.getName()` returns "UsersloggedIn.txt" in your case. This is a relative path to this file in the current directory. If you run the program in the same directory it should work with `getName()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath(), true);
```

Instead of file.getName() in your code.File.getName() method returns only the name of the file or directory,not the absolute path;

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check if the files exists or not, beside that it works fine for me.

Comment: checking is essential it is required, actually this condition checks if the file doesnt exist then creat file and then write in it, if it exists then just append in it.It has nothing to do with writing. anyways my code is working fine now I passed "file" instead of "file.getName()" in constructor. Ypou can also try this.

Comment: Ok thanks you. I just thought that the `FileWriter` checks it automatically.